# MySQL insert does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert data in mysql database.when i am trying to insert my query using PHP MyAdmin then work but if i am tring to insert from my php site from submission the not work some text not insert.

my text

http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/gacode/

§ 16-11-125.1.  Definitions

As used in this part, the term:

my form submission insert only this text

http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/gacode/

my query

```
$test='http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/gacode/

§ 16-11-125.1.  Definitions 

   As used in this part, the term:';
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_unicode_ci'");

$queryc = "INSERT INTO `table` (data17)values ('".addslashes($test)."')";
mysql_query($queryc) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Don't use `addslashes()`. If you have to escape your input, use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php); or better yet, move into the 21st century and use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: You are not testing the results of any of your queries to see if they were actually successful.  At a minimum, you should do this to help debug problems such as this.  Of course, you also should not be using the deprecated `mysql` extension.

Comment: Don't use any of the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions (including `mysql_real_escape_string()`). Use prepared statements

Comment: in addition to the don't use mysql_*. Have a look at PDO: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
Or mysqli: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

for the database connection, it should be:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test') or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

for the query, it should be:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $queryc) or die(mysqli_error($conn);
```

remember, the mysqli_query's arguments are database connection, query
also, it would be better if the query ($queryc) was:

```
$queryc = "INSERT INTO `table` (data17)values mysqli_real_escape_string($test))";
```